# How can I protect myself from Perils of the Warp?

Tags: dark-heresy-1e

Ok, I understand that the cause of Perils is based entirely upon the luck of the dice, and that a Psyker can purchase abilities to reduce the chance of being affected by/invoking the Perils of the Warp. However, as a Techpriest I'm really at the mercy of the Dice Gods.

To give some background, my Techpriest (Hadden) is a very logical character, to the point where he almost rejects the ability of the Psyker(s) in the party. From an RP perspective, these Warp events are inexplicable, purely due to the fact that he doesn't have enough information to accurately quantify them. While he has made the connection to the Psyker being the source of these events, he is ignorant to the cause of them.

Some examples of these situations are:

1. During a raid on a warehouse, after several enemies violently convulsing and falling from the gangway to their death (Hadden was standing in front of the Psyker, with his back to her, and she was casting Spasms at the enemy). Suddenly, without explanation, his Potentia Coil just shut down.
2. While watching a duel in an arena, Hadden was simply minding his own business, and unbeknownst to him, the Psyker was again casting Spasms to rig the game. All of a sudden, a giant ball of lightning engulfed the entire arena, nearly killing Hadden (I burned a Fate point at this stage to stay alive).
3. After a skirmish, the Psyker offered to heal Hadden. As soon as she did so, he was momentarily transported to another dimension. He doesn't remember much of the place, but he did gain Insanity points from the experience.
4. During a large scale combat, he was again struck in the back by bio-lightning, similar to the attack in the arena. Once again, a fate point was burned to keep the character alive. This was then immediately followed by a torrential downpour of blood rain, leading to more Insanity points.

**TL;DR:** The Psyker has dealt enough damage to me to kill me nearly 4 times, and driven me over the first threshold of insanity purely through Perils of the Warp.

So, obviously a simple solution would be to keep a fair distance between myself and the Psyker at all times, but that's impractical and doesn't gel very well in RP. Is there any other way that I can protect myself from these events, or at least reduce their effect, either through upgrades or stat improvements, or some other solution in an RP perspective?

Comment: How long have you been playing? Those four events could indicate a reckless Psyker - or the inevitable result of adventuring in the uncaring universe of Dark Heresy, depending on how spread out they are. The difference will probably affect the answers you get.

Comment: @SirTechSpec These events are fairly spaced out, we're into our second campaign arc now, so the events are fairly spaced out. As I said it's mainly down to the luck of the dice.

Comment: That being said, I don't see that it's not overly important if they are reckless or not. I'm just looking for an *in-game* method to try and protect myself from these events - not talking to the party about how they should be handling their powers.

Comment: Just to be clear, this is 1e (just going off of the tag)?

Comment: @Cthos yes, we are playing 1e

Comment: A simple solution is to kill this Psyker. Damn heretics!

Comment: @ShadowKras we already have one or two wary eyes on the Psyker. But I don't feel like that would ultimately be fair, as the player is not *intentionally* trying to inflict this upon the group. It's a by-product of their ability, so we can all agree to let it slide

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Cheap, possibly not effective

You can pick up a **Charm** (from the core book). It has no mechanical benefits aside from when bad things happen to random characters you're exempt (unless *everyone* in the party has a charm).

### Expensive, useful against non-physical psyker powers

**Psy-Jammer** - (Page 190, Inquisitor's handbook): +20 bonus on rolls to resist Psychic powers, +10 bonus to resist posession. Useless against direct damage.

### Expensive, useful against attacks

**Force Fields** -
This might not help since a perils of the warp roll might not be considered an "attack" per se, but this gives you a percentage chance to avoid damage.

The most useful one I know of is in Dark Heresy: Ascension (page 145): the **Null blocker**. It's only effective against psychic powers (whereas the other force fields are useful against all attacks), but it's got the highest percentage chance to avoid damage. It also doesn't have a cost listed because it uses the Ascension requisition system, so getting hold of one might be tricky.

### What about gear jamming or malfunctioning?

Not much I know of to preempt that, but you can carry around **Sacred Machine oil** (core book) to unjam stuff quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Have the player play conservatively, specially when trouble are worthless. There are things like the meditation skil, warp dampener  (can't remember where) and casting at a lower rating that will really help.

It won't save all situations, but a lot of your security rests on his choice so your characters can be hard on his, so he takes steps to prevent troubles. I had a Psyker at my table for some times. We had *almost* no problems.

Comment: Yeah, The player is playing a little recklessly, but the payoff is that there is no end of excitement in the game. I don't want to ruin the fun by asking them to hold off a bit, if there are other ways to dampen the effect on myself.

Comment: Well, maybe not all the time, but for a couple of Thrones, was it worth it ? Keep the two-edged sword for the medium to big baddies.